# Customizing image view in openFlow Library

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have to use openFlow library in my iphone project.If anyone used the openFlow library knows that images comes in it.I want to ask can is it possible to customize the the imageview in which images come as I want to add a share and + button which expands and shrink the image which are coming in the flow.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is solved? if not then you can use a one tricky way. on the home screen where you are showing Cover Flow add a uibutton and set frame according to your cover flow image view. and also set the event of this.

May be it solved your problem.

Thx

Comment: @mithesh there is one problemon that button click I want to include share options which includes three button share with friends,family ,others.So the problem is how will I recognize which image is currently in the flow that I want to share.

Comment: I am sorry but when I tested this approach does not seems good beacuse when we move images then view remain there and that looks odd.Help me in solving this..

Comment: i am really thankful to you mitesh thanks a lot for your valuable help.

Answer (score 1):

In "AFItemview.m" method "initWithFrame" where you are adding image view add one button like this :

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        self.opaque = YES;
        self.backgroundColor = NULL;
        verticalPosition = 0;
        horizontalPosition = 0;

        // Image View
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        imageView.opaque = YES;
        [self addSubview:imageView];

        UIButton *Btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        Btn.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,50,50);
        [Btn setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self addSubview:Btn];

    }

    return self;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: thanks a lot it worked but still there is a problem I make a method that should get called on that button click.But it is not getting called.Please help me on this issue also.....

Comment: do you know which method is responsible for showing images in coverflow